# Ffmpeg streming rtsp command runs ok on windows but not working on linux plataform(docker container, wsl and so on)

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, rtsp

I can run this command with no problem on the windows:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://user:password@10.11.12.11:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0" \
  -listen 1 \
  -f mp4 \
  -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov \
  http://localhost:8085
```

The command above runs as expected, streaming my IP Camera over localhost port `8085`.

But when I try to run this same command in linux(especially in the Docker container) I got an error:

> Output file #0 does not contain any stream

What I am doing wrong? Maybe some special chars on linux must be avoid? I tried putting some '' char to escape special chars but with no success.

I need run this command on docker container to streaming an ip camera.